# How to slit a text field with values separated by a ; so that the values are returned desperately in one result set?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, split, sql-server-2008-r2

[image]

Sorry all details are in the Image stuggling to get the text on
Please advise me on this
Regard Lee'Roy

Here is my split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
declare @idx int     
declare @slice varchar(8000)     

select @idx = 1     
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

while @idx!= 0     
begin     
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
    if @idx!=0     
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
    else     
        set @slice = @String     

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
    if len(@String) = 0 break     
end 
return     
end
```

Comment: Please, we want text - not images!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Sorry the text doesn't want to add let me try again

Comment: You'll need something like `INNER JOIN YourSplitFunction(ListOfNames,';') AS splitted ON YourTable.TheColumn LIKE '%' + splitted.OneValue + '%'`. This should bind all rows for each name separately...

Comment: The (Note:) at the end of the list is also included in the text field , it was just slit and it added to the end of the list

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you will need to create a function that splits your text values and returns a table for you to join on.

There are numerous ways to do this and most of them would be far too involved to include in this Q&A format*.  The best write up you will probably get is from [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

** Which I know is slightly against the rules on answers here, but googling "String split function SQL Server" will get you something useful should the link above die*